# How do I get ID of a button selected?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have lots of items that are displayed. It's in a while loop in which there name,instructions etc is displayed as well as a button

So, each item has it's own image,instructions etc.

I'm wondering how can I get the ID of that item that the button was selected?

Basically, i want to get the ID of that recipe and insert it into the database

Comment: If you must do it in PHP, you can use URL parameters (`my-page.php?item=my-id`), look in to [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: You can put the ID in a `<input type="hidden" name="idContainer" value="id" />` field

Comment: what ID you want? Can explain more in detail.

Comment: @infinitezero Will this get the ID of each one?How will this work?

Comment: @Rafee like i explained, there is lots of items all with name,instructions and a button EACH. once each button is selected, i need the ID to put into the database,each one has a unique ID? I just dont know how i can get it

Comment: @Ellen so basically, you want ID of that item from Database and you want that Database ID to be html ID of he button?

Comment: Yes all i need is the ID of it to i can insert it into another table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden fields to send additional information with your form. This basically works like any other input field, except, that the user does not see it in the front end.

```
<form method="GET" action="target.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value="myHiddenValue" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And to read the data

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['myHiddenField']) ){
  echo 'Hidden field value: '.$_GET['myHiddenField'];
}
?>
```

You can also use this with `POST` instead of `GET`

edit:
In your case, just put the hidden field in your loop:

```
 while ($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
 {
     ?>
     <?= $dbRow['Name'] ?>
    <br/>
    <img src="<?= $dbRow['Picture'] ?>" width="150" height="150"/>
    <br/>
    <?= $dbRow['Instructions"'] ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Complete" class="button-recipe"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!--<h4><?= $dbRow["RecipeID"] ?> I put this in even though i dont want it to be displayed, but I'm not sure how else i can get the ID? -->
       <input type="hidden" name="recipeID" value="<?= $dbRow['RecipeID'];" />
        <?php 
        }
```

You can then get the recipe ID with $_POST['recipeID'], once you clicked submit.

Comment: Is this including the input button i already have?I tried this but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: unfortunately its still not bringing me back an ID, still NULL

Comment: Are you sure `$dbRow['RecipeID']` contains the right value? Please show, how you've adapted the code and how you read the form.

Comment: see changes to post @infinitezero

Comment: You don't have the hidden field in your form. Compare it to my example. Also, you access form data with `$_POST['nameOfTheInputField']` or `$_GET['nameOfTheInputField']` (see also my example)

Answer (score 0):

```
## Use this php code its working according your database ##
<?php 

if(issset($_POST['submit'])){
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
/*your user id here i can use static for example*/
$User='1';

 $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO User (User, ID) VALUES (:User, :ID)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':User' =>$User,
        ':ID' =>$ID
));
}

    <?php
       while ($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
?>
           <h4><?php echo $dbRow["Name"]; ?></h4><img src="<?php echo $dbRow['Picture']; ?>" width='150' height='150' /><br> <?php echo $dbRow["Instructions"]; ?><br><form method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="RecipeID" value="<?php echo $dbRow['RecipeID']; ?>">
<input type='submit' name='submit' value= "Recipe_<?php echo $dbRow['RecipeID']; ?>" class='button-recipe'>
</form><!--close the form-->
<?php
            }



     ?>
```

Comment: How does this add anything new to my answer?

Comment: just use text input fields inside the form and if you want to dispaly after button click you need to get that input field similar to id

Comment: now use this php code i think should usefull for you